# Difference between set_index and index_col

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I am reading in a csv file that is ~70K rows and merging it with a dataframe that is around 84 million rows. I want to have the index columns be `A` and `B` for both to merge on. When I read in the 70K csv using `df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col = ['A','B])` and then merge on the index, it takes about 15-20 seconds. However, when I read it in by simply doing `df = pd.read_csv(file)` and then `df.set_index(['A','B']` and then merge it with the 84M row DF on the index, it takes ~15 minutes. Is there any significant difference between the two? Is `set_index` lazy?

Comment: when you use `index_col`, you are setting the index while reading so it takes only the time for reading. However, when you use `set_index`, you're reading and then set the index so the time spent is the time of reading + time of setting the index.

Comment: But it takes only a second to set the index. Then when I do the merge it takes so much longer

Comment: `df.set_index(['A','B']` doesn't change `df`, it returns a *new dataframe* (which you didn't use). Try `df.set_index(['A','B'], inplace=True)`

Comment: I believe I did df = df.set_index(['A','B']). That's doesn't overwrite df?

Comment: Can you show both code snippets?